# cannot post form in node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am very much beginner with node.js.

There is a sample form with that I am trying to insert values in database-

Here is my test page-

```
<form action="/create" method="POST" class="form-horizontal"  enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
     <input type="text" id="username_input" name="username">
     <input type="text" id="password_input" name="password">
     <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Insert" class="btn">
</form>
```

**Trying to post it-**

I created **test.js** file and writing post method in it-

```
exports.list = function (req, res) {
    req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        console.log(con)
        app.post("/create", function (req, res) {
            var username = req.body.username,
     password = req.body.password;
            console.log(username);
            console.log(password);

            connection.query('INSERT INTO users(email,password) VALUES', (username, password), function (err, rows) {

                if (error) {

                    console.log(error.message);
                } else {
                    console.log('succes');

                }

            });

        });
    });
}
```

But this didn't work.
I tried writing post method in main **server.js** file also-

```
app.post("/create", function (req, res) {
        var username = req.body.username,
 password = req.body.password;
        console.log(username);
        console.log(password);

        connection.query('INSERT INTO users(email,password) VALUES', (username, password), function (err, rows) {

            if (error) {

                console.log(error.message);
            } else {
                console.log('succes');

            }

        });

    });
```

but this didn't work also.

I am following current settings in **server.js** file-

```
/**
* Module dependencies.
*/

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , index_form = require('./routes/index_form')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , test = require('./routes/test')
  , mysql = require('mysql')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , mongoose = require('mongoose');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'pass@123'
});

var app =express();

app.configure(function () {
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function () {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/test', test.test);
app.get('/users', user.list);
app.get('/index_form', index_form.index_form)

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Kindly guide me through this all , How do I make my form post with node.js?

Comment: "This did not work" is not going to help us and you. Tell us exactly what happened when you attempted to do the *POST* in a browser. What was the server's console output? What was the browser's output? Try to capture the browser's network communication too (using dev tools).

Comment: @alandarev, there is nothing comes in console, It just shows me `cannot POST /create` message.

Comment: Add some console.log statements to see whether the code is being executed at all, and if it is - where the flow stops. What is that "cannot POST /create" message? What is *It*? Browser? The browser does not return coded error like 404? See the status of response in browser dev tools, if it is **200**, then apparantly your server works.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try putting `app.post("/create", test.test);` into your current **server.js** after your GET routes yet? Because what I saw here your current **server.js** does not have any POST request.